# Extracting and saving attachments from maildir, deduplicated

Tags: email, archive, attachment, maildir, deduplication

I would like to know if there exists a solution for archiving email, stripping out the attachments and saving them separately, deduplicated?

The ideal would be a maildir-setup, with a script running over the messages, extracting the attachments, using e.g. hard links for existing/identical attachments, leaving a link/URL to the saved attachment left in the message.

Does anything like this exist, as scripts or anything that can be run on a linux server?

AFAIK Zimbra is set up similar, with a custom maildir+database backed storage, however, I would like something a bit more "transparent" for my archiving needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Dovecot](http://www.dovecot.org/) does exactly this (Single Instance Storage) now with their [dbox](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailboxFormat/dbox) maildir format.

Comment: but it is a planned feature and not currently available?

Comment: It was introduced with 2.0.6 in Oct 2010

Comment: Ok, but is it ready for production? In the wiki (not updated) it says it's a "planned feature", in the announcement in Oct'10 it says "This feature hasn't had much testing yet, so be careful with it.".